# Can a filtered ng-repeat become a ui-router state in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I'm using ng-repeat to list photos and to filter them by genre:

```
<div class="partial-view" ui-view>
    <div class="portfolio" ng-controller="PortfolioCtrl">
        <ul class="genres">
            <li ng-repeat="genre in genres">
                <a ng-href=""
                   ng-click="searchText.string = genre.slug"
                   ng-class="{active: searchText.string == genre.slug}"
                   ng-bind-html="genre.name"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <input class="search" ng-model="searchText.string" type="text" placeholder="Search for photos"/>

        <div>
            <article class="photo" ng-repeat="photo in photos | filter: searchText.string">
                <a>
                    <img ng-src="{{photo.url}}" alt="{{photo.title}}"/>
                </a>
            </article>
        </div>
</div>
```

I would like to use ui-router in order to have a url for each genre?

When I select a genre in my menu (by clicking of 'ul.genres > li > a') it would update the url without reloading the page and when I visit that url it would bring me back to that state with the photos filtered. Is that possible?

Here is my ui-router config:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('appApp').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
            .state('portfolio', {
                url: '/portfolio',
                templateUrl: '/views/portfolio.html',
                controller: 'PortfolioCtrl'
            })
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
}());
```

I would like to have /portfolio/genre as url for the genres if possible.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an ng-click on the click of the li's and on the click function, you can change the location of your page, with parameters being passed the way you want..

Your ng-route state will look like this :

```
 .state('portfolio', {
            url: '/portfolio',
            templateUrl: '/views/portfolio.html/:portfolio/:genre',
            controller: 'PortfolioCtrl'
        })
```

And then in your controller, you can capture the parameters as,

```
 $scope.requestedPortFolio = $routeParams.portfolio;
 $scope.requestedGenre = $routeParams.genre;
```

and then you can display the data in the view based on this selections.

Comment: Can you show me how to pass the option on the click please? should I use $stateParams instead of $routeParams if I use ui-router? Are you sure you didn't get mixed up with url and the templateUrl ? I need url: '/portfolio/:genre' ... thanks for your help